# Xcode (creating app for mac os). WebView does't download page

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, webview

library file (AppDelegate.h) :

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{

    @private
   __unsafe_unretained NSWindow *window;
   __unsafe_unretained WebView *wview;


}


@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet WebView *wview;



@end
```

Xcode did not compile my code, before i add __unsafe_unretained  in private (Existing instance variable 'window' for property 'window' with  assign attribute must be __unsafe_unretained).

main file (AppDelegate.m) :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window;
@synthesize wview;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    [[wview mainFrame]loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://vk.com"]]];

}

- (IBAction)wview:(id)sender {


    [[wview mainFrame]loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vk.com"]]];

}

@end
```

Comment: Before calling `loadRequest` put in `NSLog(@"View: %@, Frame: %@", wview, [wview mainFrame]);` and let us know what it prints.

Comment: It's not work (((
Project is compiled, but site doesn't load

Comment: I repeat, put in the log statement and see what it tells you.

Comment: "Type name requires a specifier or qualifier"
"Expected parameter declarator"